# Qt Designer can't promote QMainWindow

Tags: qt, pyside, designer, qmainwindow

There is something I do not understand about `Qt Designer`. I have been working with it for a while now, and still I always end up editing the .ui files manually.

As it can be seen in *every single* tutorial on Qt, one of the very first thing you do when you create a GUI is to subclass `QMainWindow` - in order to catch and redefine the `closeEvent()` function, for example.

However, it is not possible to subclass ("promote") `QMainWindow` in Qt Designer - you can do it with many other class, but not this one.

What I usually do is edit the .ui file and change:

```
<class>MainWindow</class>
  <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
```

by:

```
< widget class="MyMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
```

So that my code can subclass `QMainWindow` properly in my code:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, object):
    ''' I can redefine closeEvent here! '''
```

Obviously, this is weird - and I probably miss something about the right way to do it with Designer. But I cannot find any explanation.

Why is it not possible to subclass `QMainWindow` in Designer, or how to structure my application differently to avoid the need for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You generally don't need to promote the root element of UI tree. If you properly initialize your class using UI file, you can redefine `closeEvent` without it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894550/344347) shows how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this answer. But what this shows is that someone had the same issue and created a hack to work around it. Now it is not so clear to me if this is a Pyside bug. When using Qt/C++ or PyQt, calling load() from within an instance of the Ui file top-level class directly maps the loaded widget to the current instance? This is definitely not explained like this on the QUiLoader documentation. Still puzzled.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old. I somehow ran into the same problem. I want to use docking features in a sub window. When I tried to promote the QMinWindow, I don't see it in the list. Then I tried using QWidget in the drop down list, it magically went through.

Just my experience.