# Defining keyboard shortcuts for child widgets contained in a main window with Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I've been using Qt Designer a lot more in my workflow recently, and I've been struggling on getting signals/actions working with promoted child widgets.

For the sake of this question, I have one parent `QMainWindow` holding the menu bar, and a child `QWidget` with a search bar. It is done by promoting a basic `QWidget` to `ChildWidget` and having that in the main window.

For reference, it looks like this with 2 child widgets:

[image]

I would like to set a keyboard shortcut of CTRL+F to focus on the search bar (triggering `MainWindow.childWidget.searchBar.setFocus`).

**Things I've tried:**

---

**Create a QAction on the widget** - it doesn't work with the signal/slot editor unless it is "used", and I'm not able to add a `QMenuBar` or `QToolBar` to a `QWidget` so it remains unused.

Connecting an action signal to a slot also doesn't mark it as used.

[image]

[image]

---

**Promote the child widget as `QMainWindow` instead of `QWidget`, and add a `QToolBar`** - [it's not possible to promote to `QMainWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026833/qt-designer-cant-promote-qmainwindow).

[image]

---

**Define custom signal/slot** - it doesn't actually create them, it's for adding already existing ones on the widget, so it'll error due to undefined variables. Also the parent widget can only trigger a child widget slot, so I can't have the main window emit a child widget signal.

[image]

---

Combining the signals/slots/action ways mentioned above, if I define a custom slot with the parent widget and connect to that, it would actually work if it allowed you to write `myAction.triggered.emit` as the slot name, but the validation doesn't let you.

[image]

---

Is there any way to get keyboard shortcuts working in promoted child widgets with Qt Designer? To be clear, I *can* do this in code, but I'd like to know if without code is possible.

---

For some extra details  as to why overriding the child widgets isn't really an option, here's my current setup. I coded a `ui2py` module that takes a `layout.ui` file and returns the `MainWindow` class, such that my entire UI setup is `self.ui = ui2py.build(LAYOUT_FILE)(); self.ui.setupUi(self)`.

Inside `layout.ui`, if I have an `import sublayout.ui`, then it'll intercept that build a class around it, basically allowing me to promote ui files directly from within Qt Designer. Here's the code with an example docstring of how it works:

```
_UI_PROMOTE_TEMPLATE = """

try:
    from {mod}.{file} import {cls!s}

except ImportError:
    def {cls!s}(parent):
        import os
        import {mod}
        import ui2py
        uiDir = os.path.dirname({mod}.__file__)
        cls = ui2py.build(os.path.join(uiDir, '{file}'))

        class {cls}(QWidget, cls):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                super({cls}, self).__init__(parent)
                self.setupUi(self)
        return {cls}(parent)"""


def _fixUiPromote(code):
    """Build UI files for promotions when needed.
    The import is still attempted first as its possible there is an
    actual widget living inside of a "ui.py" file.

    Old:
        from a.b.layout.ui import MainLayout

    New:
        try:
            from a.b.layout.ui import MainLayout
        except ImportError:
            def MainLayout(parent):
                import os
                import a.b
                import ui2py
                uiDir = os.path.dirname(a.b.__file__)
                cls = ui2py.build(os.path.join(uiDir, 'layout.ui'))

                class MainLayout(QWidget, cls):
                    def __init__(self, parent):
                        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(parent)
                        self.setupUi(self)
                return MainLayout(parent)
    """
    code, replacements = re.subn(
        r'\nfrom (.*)\.([A-z][A-z0-9]*\.ui) import ([A-Z][A-z0-9]*)'.encode('utf-8'),
        lambda match: _UI_PROMOTE_TEMPLATE.format(
            mod=match.group(1).decode('utf-8'),
            file=match.group(2).decode('utf-8'),
            cls=match.group(3).decode('utf-8'),
        ).encode('utf-8'),
        code,
    )
    logger.debug('UI files promoted: %s', replacements)
    return code
```

Comment: Why not just add a "focus search bar" item to the main-window menu and connect it to a slot in the promoted widget?

Comment: The promoted widget is just a UI file that gets converted to python under the hood, so I can't add any custom signals/slots to it.

Comment: Of course you can. There's nothing stopping you from creating a simple wrapper class for the ui file. Qt Designer doesn't care what the actual implementation is. All it cares about are names.

Comment: It's a bit hard to write the details in the comment so I made an edit showing the code. By "converted under the hood" I mean the wrapper class is automatically generated using regex. Short of adding in support for dynamically generating slots I don't think there's a clean way to do that. Like I mentioned it's not a big problem, I _could_ define the widget in python and promote that instead, was just looking if there was a way I could automate this all entirely from designer :)

Comment: Well, it rather looks like you've made a rod for your own back here. You seem to be throwing away most of the main benefits of widget-promotion for the sake of automating what appears to be a relatively minor step in the development process.