# Using QT Designer and PyQt, how do I fill an empty widget defined in one .ui file with a widget defined in another .ui file?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Let's say I have a `MainWindow.ui` that defines the layout of `MainWindow.py`, where `MainWindow.py` looks a little like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui')
```

`MainWindow.ui` holds two (actually three) widgets. A simple QLabel `text_lbl` for argument's sake, and an empty QWidget `sub_widget`. These two widgets are held in `central_widget`.

We also have a `SubWidget.ui`. `SubWidget.ui` can be anything, really, but let's say it holds a lot of labels and spinboxes. `SubWidget.py` looks a lot like `MainWindow.py`, except it holds a lot of signals and slots:

```
class SubWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('SubWidget.ui')

        # A lot of interesting stuff here.
```

What I want to do, is put an instance of `SubWidget` in `MainWindow`'s sub_widget. The obvious thing for me to do would be to add the following lines of code to `MainWindow.py`'s `__init__`:

```
from SubWidget import SubWidget  # Though really this shouldn't be in
                                     # __init__, but you get the idea.
self.ui.sub_widget = SubWidget()
```

Which simply doesn't do anything. I eventually achieved rendering `SubWidget` *over* the main window's contents and complaining about `MainWindow` already having a layout, but I lost that code in the midst of all fiddling.

How do I achieve this?

edit: I forgot to mention. `self.ui.central_layout.addWidget(SubWidget())` visually achieves what I'm trying to do, but if I ever decide to add UI elements beneath that in the .ui file, that simply won't work.

Comment: you could use the widget directly by promoting the widget in qtdesigner

Comment: in the cpp qtdesigner you can right-click a widget and "Promote to..." a custom widget (that you coded)

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. Nor can I figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: I've carefully perused your post and I am sure **widget promotion** is the right way you should look into.

Comment: There's one caveat, though: I want to be able to eventually fill the sub_widget with any QWidget or derivative thereof.

Comment: If you were interested in dynamic promotion of widgets at runtime, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011953/quiloader-createwidget-equivalent-in-pyqt

Answer (score 0):

If you can't, or for whatever reason just don't want to, use widget promotion, then the most obvious solution is to make the `SubWidget` a child of the place-holder widget.

Since the place-holder widget doesn't yet have a child, you can't give it layout in Qt Designer, so you will have to do it all programmatically:

```
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.empty_widget)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.ui.sub_widget = SubWidget()
    layout.addWidget(self.ui.sub_widget)
```